# To detect connected printer then disconnect and remove printer using CUPS library in Swift language on Mac OS

Tags: swift, macos, cups

How can I programmatically disconnect and remove all printers in Mac OS as soon as they connect using the CUPS library in Swift? I've attempted to achieve this by using the `cupsRemoveDest()` and `cupsFreeDest()` functions in Swift, and while they appear to disconnect the printer, it still remains visible in "`System Settings > Printers & Scanners.`" Is it possible to completely remove the printer using CUPS in Swift?
To detect printers I have used `cupsGetDest()`

In summary, I'm looking for a way to remove printers from Mac OS via Swift and CUPS so that they are no longer visible in the system settings.